# SSI exec error while processing directive on Windows

Tags: php, ssi

I'm running bWAPP v2.2 SSI injection on my computer (http://localhost/bWAPP/ssii.php - or you can watch someone's video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyw3e6UKN-w). On the page there is a form with two fields (first name and last name). When I fill the last name with `<!--#exec cmd="dir" -->`, I got the following error

```
[an error occurred while processing this directive]
```

But echo command such as `<!--#echo var="DOCUMENT_URI" -->` is working. I'm on Windows 10 with Apache/2.4.25 and PHP 5.6.30. Here is the Apache error log

```
[Wed May 03 14:58:06.517706 2017] [win32:error] [pid 16960:tid 1864] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : [client ::1:63531] AH02100: Failed to open cgi file dir for testing, referer: http://localhost/bWAPP/ssii.php
[Wed May 03 14:58:06.518706 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 16960:tid 1864] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : [client ::1:63531] AH01226: don't know how to spawn cmd child process: C:/xampp/htdocs/bWAPP/ssii.shtml, referer: http://localhost/bWAPP/ssii.php
[Wed May 03 14:58:06.518706 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 16960:tid 1864] [client ::1:63531] AH01229: execution failure for parameter "cmd" to tag exec in file C:/xampp/htdocs/bWAPP/ssii.shtml, referer: http://localhost/bWAPP/ssii.php
```

What should I do to make SSI exec work?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem too and yet, I couldn't find any solution for the error. Instead I found another alternative command here `<!--#include virtual="../" -->` for the replacement of  `<!--#exec cmd="dir" -->`.